# how to get correct dimensions from ecmascript inside svg on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, svg, viewport

I could not find a way to get the exact width and height of the screen/window with ecmascript,
when asked from inside a svg on iOS and Android devices. One of the problems is, that mobile devices are only able to return the right dimensions when the meta tag "viewport" with the attribute content="width=device-width" is used. Svg do not know the meta tag. The style sheet   @viewport {width: device-width;} won't work with the webkit standard browsers on iOS and Android.

My ecmascript program works very well inside svg, when called from desktop browsers but not from mobile browsers.